# 000 webhost #1045 - Access denied for user

Tags: phpmyadmin

I have recently signed up for 000webhost and created a new database. when I try to enter the database via phpMyAdmin I receive a security warning message stating

> The information you have entered on this page will be sent over an
>   insecure connection and could be read by a third party.

Once I click continue I get an error message stating

> #1045 - Access denied for user

Could someone please help me enter this database?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I presume the "insecure connection" message is because your host is not running phpMyAdmin on an HTTPS site. You could ask them about this.

About the access denied message, this is usually because of incorrect login credentials. Double-check the username and password provided by your host and try again. You might also ask your host for assistance.

Comment: Actually this happens even though the credentials are right

Answer (score 6):

Even I faced the login error. Tried for two hours after creating the login. But it worked on the next day. SO I suppose, It takes some time for the login to work. So if you have just created the login, then just wait for a day and hope for the best

Answer (score 5):

Just give it a day to settle, I activated mine one day at about 3 o clock pm and then i came back the next day at 9am and then it started working, and did not give me the error any more

Answer (score 2):

For this reason, you have to wait for maximum one day to set database properly because 000webhost is free so it takes time to create a database for a user.After one day your PHP admin will open properly